# Text is not showing in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

the `Label` (`showpw`) (inside: `def passwort_gen`) I placed on the grid is not visible in the application window. When I run the code and press the button, the original button moves up to make place for the text, like it should, the text however is not visible.

Below you can see the entire project code. It's my first project using Tkinter so I apologize for the messy structure.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import pyperclip as pc

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=300)
canvas.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=3)

#Header
Header = tk.StringVar()
text = tk.Label(root, textvar=Header, font="helvetica")
Header.set("Passwort Generator")

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!§$%&/()=?*#'@"
passwords = []

text.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)

def neues_passwort():
    gen = tk.StringVar()
    gen_btn = tk.Button(root, textvar=gen, command=lambda:passwort_gen(), font="helvetica")
    gen.set("Passwort Generieren")
    gen_btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
    Header.set("Neues Passwort")

def passwort_gen():
    for p in range(1):
        password = ""
        for c in range(12):
            password += random.choice(chars)
    pwtext = tk.StringVar()
    showpw = tk.Label(root, textvar=pwtext, font="helvetica", fg="#000000")
    pwtext.set = "Dein Passwort ist:", password, ". Es wurde zum Clipboard hinzugefügt"
    showpw.grid(columnspan=3, column=1, row=2,)
    pc.copy(password)



#button
text = tk.StringVar()
browse_btn = tk.Button(root, textvar=text, command=lambda:neues_passwort(), font="helvetica")
text.set("neues Passwort")
browse_btn.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: pwtext.set(...) not pwtext.set = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwtext.set` is a function, not a string container. Use `pwtext.set("Dein Passwort ist:" + password + ". Es wurde zum Clipboard hinzugefügt")` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.